# Sequence has 2 subsequences, one of which converges and one diverging, so will be say the sequence is diverging?

Tags: real-analysis

Lets say we have a sequence, and it has 2 subsequence one which is diverging to +$\infty$, and the other is lets say converging to zero, so what will we call the sequence to be?
(Also what I think is it would most probably be called diverging, so if I have to show is it diverging, so can I just say that as this subsequence is diverging and the other one is converging, so thus the whole sequence is diverging?)

Comment: Yes you can.___

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence converges to $l$ if and only if every subsequence also converges to $l$. So if one subsequence is divergent, the original sequence must be divergent too.

Comment: so in my proof can i just directly write that as both the subsequence is not convergent thus the whole series is not convergent

Comment: @Kutubkhan Bhatiya: *so in my proof can i just directly write that as both the subsequence is not convergent thus the whole series is not convergent* --- This will depend on what you are allowed to use (without proof) at this point, which varies with book, course, teacher, etc. as well as location in the book, where you are at in the course, etc.